# Выбрать первый и последний элемент родителя

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, slick.js

Пытаюсь найти подходящее решение, использую Slick Slider.
Имеется вот такое:

```
<div class="slick-track">
 <div class="slick-slide"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide"></div>
</div>
```

Когда меняется страница слайдера, то три элемента получают дополнительные классы, "средний" слайд страницы получает особый класс, например:

```
<div class="slick-track">
 <div class="slick-slide"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide slick-active"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide slick-active slick-center"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide slick-active"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide"></div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="slick-track">
 <div class="slick-slide"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide slick-active"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide slick-active slick-center"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide slick-active"></div>
 <div class="slick-slide"></div>
</div>
```

Какой селектор CSS или JQuery можно применить чтобы получить первый "slick-active" и третий "slick-active" в этом списке (или первый и последний из трёх "slick-active")? Элементы нужно выбрать по отдельности, то есть отдельно левый от slick-center и правый от slick-center соответственно. nth-child тут не выйдет применить, поскольку слайдер должен скроллиться и соответственно будет меняться порядок активных элементов.

Comment: Что значит получить? Не совсем ясно.

Comment: предыдущий `$('.slick-center').prev('.slick-active');` и,  следующий `$('.slick-center').next('.slick-active');`

Comment: @KirillKorushkin в смысле правильный селектор чтобы можно было взаимодействовать с элементом. Написать нечто вроде: $('.slick-track .slick-active:last-item-of-list').css('background-color','black'); и добавить последнему элементу чёрный фон.

На вопрос хоть и ответили, но уточнить стоит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var active = $('.slick-active');

var first = active.eq(0);
var last = active.eq( active.length - 1 );
```

или...

```
var first = $('.slick-center').prev();
var last = $('.slick-center').next();
```

К слову, если это дело нужно только для добавления стилей, можно на CSS)

```
.slick-active { background-color: red; }
              /* Все активные, но в итоге применится только к первому: 
               * Следующие селекторы перебьют этот */

.slick-active.slick-center { background-color: blue; } /* центральный */

.slick-center + .slick-active { background-color: orange; } /* третий */

.slick-center ~ .slick-active { background-color: orange; } /* тоже третий */
```

Answer (score 0):

При каждой смене слайда нужно заново ловить классы.
Вот доработанный пример:

```
$('.your-slider').on('init', function(slick){
var active = $('.your-slider .slick-active');
var first = active.eq(0);
var last = active.eq( active.length - 1 );
first.addClass('test');
last.addClass('test');
});

$('.your-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
var active = $('.your-slider .slick-active');
var first = active.eq(0);
var last = active.eq( active.length - 1 );
active.removeClass('test')
first.addClass('test');
last.addClass('test');
});
```